podman volume overlay mount for root of filesystem
I have a directory which contains a partial root filesystem which I would like to overlay-mount in a container.
Even using a simple empty directory however leads to podman to error out, eg:
$> mkdir /tmp/overlayroot
$> podman run --rm -i -v /tmp/overlayroot:/:O -t myimage:latest
Error: runc: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found

Is my understanding wrong? Am I trying to achieve something impossible?
Note that a COPY of the contents is not what I am after (for performance reasons).

I don't think this will work the way you want to. Reading the docs regarding "overlay volume mounts" it looks like this works in the opposite direction to what you want.

In overlay terms, the source directory is the lower, and the container storage directory is the upper. Modifications to the mount point are destroyed when the container finishes executing, similar to a tmpfs mount point being unmounted.

If your version is recent enough there are some advanced options that might do what you want:

For advanced users, the overlay option also supports custom non-volatile upperdir and workdir for the overlay mount. Custom upperdir and workdir can be fully managed by the users themselves, and Podman does not remove it on lifecycle completion. Example :O,upperdir=/some/upper,workdir=/some/work

However, this sounds very much like normal image building - is there a reason why that won't work for you?
